# Is it acceptable to copy and paste long but straightforward code instead of wrapping them into a class or function?

Tags: object-oriented, code-quality

Suppose I have a segment of code to connect to internet and show connection results like it:

```
HttpRequest* httpRequest=new HttpRequest();
httpRequest->setUrl("(some domain .com)");
httpRequest->setRequestType(HttpRequest::Type::POST);
httpRequest->setRequestData("(something like name=?&age=30&...)");
httpRequest->setResponseCallback([=](HttpClient* client, HttpResponse* response){
    string responseString=response->getResponseDataString();
        if(response->getErrorCode()!=200){
            if(response->getErrorCode()==404){
                Alert* alert=new Alert();
                alert->setFontSize(30);
                alert->setFontColor(255,255,255);
                alert->setPosition(Screen.MIDDLE);
                alert->show("Connection Error","Not Found");
            }else if((some other different cases)){
                (some other alert)
            }else
                Alert* alert=new Alert();
                alert->setFontSize(30);
                alert->setPosition(Screen.MIDDLE);
                alert->setFontColor(255,255,255);
                alert->show("Connection Error","unknown error");
            }
        }else{
            (other handle methods depend on different URL)
        }
}
```

the code is long, and it is commonly used, but the code above does not require any extra things such as custom function and class (HttpRequest and Alert are both provided by framework by default), and although the code segment is long, it is straightforward and not complex (it is long just because there are bundles of settings such as url, font size...), and the code segment has little variations among class (e.g.: url,request data, error code handle cases, normal handle cases...)

My question is, is it acceptable to copy and paste long but straightforward code instead of wrapping them in a function to reduce the dependency of code?

Comment: Imagine you have a bug in that code, such as not freeing objects you allocate. (Does your framework free the `Alert` objects?) Now imagine you have to find every copied instance of this code to fix the bug. Now imagine it's not you who has to do it, but a crazy axe murderer who knows you were the one who created all these copies in the first place.

Comment: What does "acceptable" imply?  Being able to get away with it?

Comment: And BTW, mixing networking and error display in one place is already a big no-no, IMHO.

Comment: No. Never.  Entirely unacceptable.  If you were on my project, you would no longer be on my project and you'd be on a training program or PIP.

Comment: And along comes the supervisor that says "This alert box in the middle of my screen is an absolute terror. I am watching cat jifs and the pop-up is blocking my view every time it shows up. Please move it to the upper-right." [3 weeks later](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XFkFH.jpg) "What the heck did you do?! I can no longer close my cat jifs because YOUR pop-up is covering the X in the upper-right, fix it."

Comment: The fact you even feel obligated to ask is already a sign that you shouldn't.

Comment: I think everyone here seems to think this is a bad idea. But to turn the question around, why would you NOT put this code in a separate class or function?

Comment: I it is really sooo common to use alerts in white 30px font in the middle of the screen, there'd be a standard function for that. Then again, I've been rereading your code again and again and cannot figure out why it is so important that in one ase FontColor is set before Position and in one case the other way round; there must surely be something deep hidden in the difference ... See? Repetition (esp. almost-repetition) can even make the code harder to read

Comment: Suppose you want to change something about this code later. Are you likely to want to change all instances of it together, or each one separately? If the change is likely to apply to all instances then you should wrap it in a function (to make global changes easy). If instances are likely to evolve separately then you should *not* wrap it in a function.

Comment: You can pass `"(some domain .com)"` in as a parameter and then make the code reusable.

Comment: It's frown upon in formal luncheons.

Comment: Everything is acceptable as soon as someone is ready to accept it. On my project, any project of mine, I would not accept it from anyone. There are at least 3 intermingled responsibilities in this code : requesting, handling errors, and displaying errors. At least three functions need to be extracted from this code, and that does not take into account "wrapping [the whole thing] in a function" (which does not "reduce the dependency of code". Dependencies are transitive.)

Comment: which language is that? Doesn't look like java nor C#, it could be C++ but in that case you have a tons of memory leaks.

Comment: If putting a code block into a method is a burden to you, it is a sign that you need more practice with the language, and to study it's rules so that issues of scope, passing by value/reference, etc are second nature. Beyond that, a good rule of thumb is to aim for 5 or less statements per method, to become very skeptical at 10-15, and to refactor almost always above 20.

Answer (score 87):

You need to consider the cost of change.  What if you wanted to change how connections are made?  How easy would it be?  If you have a lot of duplicated code, then finding all the places that need changing could be quite time consuming and error prone.

You also need to consider clarity.  Most likely, having to look at 30 lines of code isn't going to be as easy to understand as a single call to a "connectToInternet" function.  How much time is going to be lost trying to understand the code when new functionality needs to be added?

There are certain rare cases where duplication isn't a problem.  For example, if you are doing an experiment and the code is going to be thrown away at the end of the day.  But in general, **the cost of duplication outweighs the small time savings of not having to pull the code out into a separate function**.

See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/103235/63172

Comment: ...and who knows if these 30 lines are really the same as those other ones that you looked at previously or if somebody switched to a different port or IP address in his/her copy for whatever reason. The implicit assumption that "*any bunch of somewhat 30 lines starting with the `HttpRequest` are all the same*" is an easy to make fallacy.

Comment: @null Excellent point.  I once worked on code where there were database connection  hookups copied and pasted all over, but some had subtle differences in the setup.  I had no idea if these were important, deliberate changes, or just random differences

Answer (score 54):

No.

In fact, even your "simple" code should be split into smaller parts.  At least two.

One to make the connection and  handle the normal 200 response.  For example, what if you change from a POST to a PUT in some cases?  What if you are making zillions of these connections and need some multi-threading or connection-pooling?  Having the code in one single place, with an argument for the method, will make this much easier

Similarly, another to handle errors.  For example, if you change the color or font size of the alert.  Or you are having issues with intermittent connections and want to log the errors.

Comment: DRY: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-best-code-is-no-code-at-all/

Comment: You could also quote SRP: having a code block that has only one purpose makes it so much easier to understand and maintain..

Comment: This is one case where DRY and SRP actually align.  Sometimes they don't.

Answer (score 18):

> is it acceptable to copy and paste ...

No.

For me, the deciding argument is this one:

> ... it is commonly used ...

If you use a piece of code in *more* than one place then, *when* it changes, you have to *change* it in more than one place or you start to get inconsistencies - "odd things" start to happen (i.e. you introduce Bugs).

> it is straightforward and not complex ...

And so should be all the easier to refactor into a function.

> ... there are bundles of settings such as url, font size ...

And what do users *love* to change?  Fonts, font sizes, colours, etc., etc.

Now; in how many places will you have to change that same piece of code to get them all the same colour/font/size again?  (Recommended answer: just **one**).

> ... the code segment has little variations among class (e.g.: url,request data, error code handle cases, normal handle cases...)

Variation => function parameter(s).

Comment: "And what do users love to change? Fonts, font sizes, colours, etc" this is so deal on. Do you really want to change that in dozens of locations?

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't really have anything to do with copy and paste. If you take code from elsewhere, at the second you take the code it's *your* code and *your* responsibility, so whether it's copied or written completely by yourself doesn't make a difference.

In your alerts you make some design decisions. Most likely similar design decisions should be made for all alerts. So it's likely that you should have a method somewhere "ShowAlertInAStyleSuitableForMyApplication" or maybe a bit shorter, and that should be called.

You will have lots of http requests with similar error handling. You should likely not duplicate the error handling again and again and again but extract common error handling. Especially if your error handling gets a bit more elaborate (what about timeout errors, 401, and so on).

Answer (score 6):

Duplication is OK in some circumstances. But not in this one. That method is too complex. There is a lower limit, when duplication is easier than "factoring out" a method.

For example:

```
def add(a, b)
    return a + b
end
```

is stupid, just do a + b.

But when you get just a little, tiny bit more complex, then you're usually way over the line.

```
foo.a + foo.b
```

should become

```
foo.total
def foo
    ...
    def total
        return self.a + self.b
    end
end
```

In your case, I see four "methods". Probably in different classes. One to make the request, one to get the response, one to display errors, and some kind of call back to be called after the response returns to process the response. I personally would likely add a "wrapper" of sorts on top of that as well to make the calls easier.

In the end, to make a web request I would want a call to look something like:

```
Web.Post(URI, Params, ResponseHandler);
```

That line is what I would have all over my code. Then when I needed to make changes to "how I get stuff" I could quickly do so, with much less effort.

This also keeps the code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and helps with [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 0):

A class and/or a function is better, at least in my opinion. For once, it makes the file smaller which is a very heavy gain if you deal with web applications or applications for devices with little storage (IoT, older phones, etc.)

And obviously the best point is that if you have something to change due to new protocols, etc. you just change the content of the function and not countless of times you put this function somewhere which might even be in different files making them even harder to find and change.

I wrote a whole SQL interpreter so I could switch better from MySQL to [MySQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi) in PHP, because I just have to change my interpreter and everyting is working, although that is an a bit of an extreme example.

Answer (score 0):

In a project of any size/complexity, I want to be able to find code when I need it for the following purposes:

1. Fix it when it's broke
2. Change the functionality
3. Reuse it.

Wouldn't it be lovely, to either join a project in progress or continue to work on  a project for several years and when a new request to "connect to internet and show connection results" was in some easy to find location due to having a good design instead of relying on doing a search throughout the code for an httprequest? It's probably easier to find with Google anyway.

Don't worry, I'm the new guy and I'll refactor this block of code because I'm so upset for joining this clueless team with the awful code base or I'm now under a lot of pressure like the rest of you and will just copy and paste it. At least it will keep the boss off my back. Then when the project is truly identified as a disaster, I'll be the first to recommend we rewrite it by copying and pasting the version in the latest and greatest framework that none of us understand.

Answer (score -1):

To decide whether a code should be duplicated or moved to a function which is called twice, try to determine which is more probable:

1. It will be necessary to change both uses of the code in the same way.
2. It will be necessary to change at least one use of the code so that they differ.

In the first case, it will likely be better to have one function handle both usages; in the latter case, it will be likely be better to have separate code for the two usages.

In deciding whether a piece of code which will be used once should be written in-line or pulled out into another function, figure out how one would fully describe the function's required behavior.  If a complete and accurate description of the function's required behavior would be as long or longer than the code itself, moving the code into a separate function may make things harder to understand rather than easier.  It may still be worth doing if there's a high likelihood that a second caller will need to use the same function, and any future changes to the function will need to affect both callers, but in the absence of such consideration, readability would favor splitting things to the level where the code and a description of its required behavior would be about equally long.