# What is priming the pump? Sometimes called a priming read

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns, loops

I was taught this expression and pattern way back in the day.  Sure, the name comes from old pumps that needed to be filled with water before they could pump water, but who cares? We're talking about code here.

Some really good examples and an explanation of what the pattern accomplishes would be welcome.  How is this pattern regarded today?

Priming can sometimes get a defective loop working but at the cost of [DRY](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103233/why-is-dry-important). So it may be a brief stop on the way to a better design.  Is this considered an anti pattern?  Are there alternatives?

Comment: You'll find term "priming the pump" [in a stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27697452/1493294) and
[a book](http://faculty.orangecoastcollege.edu/sgilbert/book/07-5-SentinelLoops-B/index.html). 
The term "priming read", found  [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110927203211AAYT88O), seems much the same.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This metaphor almost certainly refers to the practice of establishing the first conditional check in a `while` loop.  If you don't do this, *the loop won't work.*  It is a well-established pattern, and it hasn't changed since the `while` loop was invented.  The requirement for setting the initial condition in a `while` loop is *not a defect.*

```cs
int i = 0; // prime the pump
while (i < 10)
{
    Console.Write("While statement ");
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i++; // set condition again
}
```

The primer can be a read statement, or whatever properly sets the initial condition.  Setting the initial condition using a read statement is called a "Priming Read."

```cs
string line;

using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("c:\\test.txt"))
{
    line = file.ReadLine(); // Priming read.
    while(line != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (line);
        line = file.ReadLine(); // Subsequent reads.   
    }
}
```

In C#, the two `Readline()` calls can be combined into a single statement within the conditional:

```cs
while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine (line);
}
```

Comment: Nice.  There are times when you need to do A and B in order with a test T exactly between them.  The usual `A T(B A)` priming pattern does this but duplicates A.  Any general alternatives to this general pattern?

Comment: See the last bit of code in my answer.

Comment: That one's a classic.  Would you ever suggest using a break?

Comment: I'm not opposed to early exits from a loop if doing so simplifies the code.  Sometimes you can just `return`.

Comment: Would love to see an example.

Comment: An example would be looking for the first occurrence of a string in each line of a text file.  You would still need the `while` loop, but once you found the string in the line you just read, you could either `break` or `return`.

Comment: Found a decent [example of code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6850411/1493294) that allows A and B to be any number of lines, avoids duplicating A, and puts a test between A and B.

Comment: While it’s not a defect, setting the initial condition outside the scope of the loop when it’s not used outside does cause a scope leak. Which is likely why they gave us the convoluted for(;;) loop.